# Lista de numeros primos menores que N no R

Tags: r

Estou pensando em um jeito de trazer quais os números primos até o limite n, porém não estou conseguindo gerar um código em R para isso.

```
numeros <- c()
div = 0

for (i in range(1:1000)) {
  div = 0
  for (j in range(1:i+1)) {
    if(i %% j == 0) {
      div = div + 1
    } else if (div == 2) {
      numeros <- c(i)
    }
  }
}
```

Este é o código que estou tentando, mas não está dando certo.

Answer (score 4):

Tem vários problemas no seu código (`range`, por exemplo não faz o que está pensando, e só está guardando o último valor de `i` em `numeros`). Mas R é funcional e vetorizado, existem abordagens melhores do que *loops*.

Pode fazer a comparação para todos os números entre 2 e n-1 vetorialmente. Por exemplo:

```
8 %% 2:7 == 0
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Com isso, pode construir uma função que verifique se é primo ou não. Use `any` para ver se há pelo menos um valor com a condição, junto com operador de negação (`!`), já que será primo se não for esse o caso. Como o número 2 é um caso especial (já que 2-1 = 1), inclui-se uma condição para ele:

```
is.prime <- function(n) {
  if (n == 2) {
    TRUE
  } else {
    !any(n %% 2:(n-1) == 0)
  }
}

is.prime(7)
#> [1] TRUE

is.prime(8)
#> [1] FALSE
```

Pode aplicar a função a qualquer vetor de números com `*apply` e usar o vetor lógico resultante para indexar:

```
numeros <- 1:100

numeros[sapply(numeros, is.prime)]
```

Ou vetoriza-la e aplicar diretamente:

```
is.prime <- Vectorize(is.prime)

numeros[is.prime(numeros)]
#> [1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Comment: Correto, erro meu ao pensar na exceção para `n %% 2:(n-1)` abaixo de 3 (2, e não 1). Resposta editada.

Answer (score 3):

Para gerar todos os números primos até um limite ou entre um limite inferior e um limite superior, existe o pacote `primes`, função `generate_primes`. Esta função está codificada em C++ e é bastante mais rápida que uma função em R base.

```
library(primes)

generate_primes(max = 100)
# [1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83
#[24] 89 97
```

Answer (score -1):

### Corrigindo o código da pergunta:

Primeira coisa que deve saber é que a função [`range()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/peruse/html/range.html) em *R*, apesar do nome, é diferente da função *Python* [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-range).
Enquanto que em *Pyton* `range()` retorna uma sequencia aberta a direita entre dois valores, em *R* `range()` retorna um vetor contendo o máximo e o mínimo do vetor de entrada. Veja o exemplo:

```r
range(1,0,5,2)
#[1] 0 5
```

Em *R* para se criar uma sequencia regular use a função [seq()](https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/base/html/seq.html)

`seq(from, to, by)`
*Argumentos*:

- `from`, `to` : os valores inicial e final da sequência.
- `by` : incremento da sequência.
  *Exemplo*:

```r
seq(0, 10, 2)      #Equivalente python ao range(0,11,2)
#[1]  0  2  4  6  8 10
```

Ou então use `:` para criar uma sequencia regular e discreta:

```r
1:10
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Outra coisa que deve ter em mente é que para adicionar um elemento a um vetor use a função [`append()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/append).

Finalmente nesse bloco de código:

```r
for (j in ...) {
    if(i %% j == 0) {
      div = div + 1
    } e̶l̶s̶e̶ if (div == 2) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Apenas remova o `else`.

Seu código deverá ficar parecido com isso:

```r
numeros <- c()
div = 0

for (i in 1:100) {
  div = 0
  for (j in 1:(i+1)) {
    if(i %% j == 0) {
      div = div + 1
    } 
  }
  if (div == 2) {
      numeros <- append(numeros, i)    
      #numeros <- c(numeros, i) obtém o mesmo resultado
  }
}

numeros
#[1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/primos2#main.r)</sup>

### Uma outra solução:

Você também pode aproveitar as características funcionais da linguagem e no caso usar a função [`sapply(X, FUN)`](https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/base/html/lapply.html) que é uma função que retorna uma lista do mesmo comprimento que `X` onde cada elemento é o resultado da aplicação da função `FUN` aos elementos de `X`.

Aplique ao vetor de entrada uma função que para cada um de seus elementos some o número de divisores menores que o próprio elemento. Então filtre o vetor  de entrada deixando passando passar apenas os elementos que possuam um único divisor.

```r
n <- 1:100

r = sapply(n, function(e) sum(e %% 1:(e-1) == 0) )  #Para cada elemento e soma o número de divisores de e menores que e
n[r %in% 1]                                         #Imprime os elementos de n que possuem apenas um único divisor.
#[1] 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/primos#main.r)</sup>

Comment: Os dois quem votaram contra eu duvido que sejam capazes de apresentarem um motivo técnico verdadeiro que justifique os seus votos. Os dois votos negativos aqui dados são votos dados de protesto que reflete apenas a falta de caráter dos votantes. E não vou para de fazer o que é certo só porque vocês não gostam, e gostem ou não eu, continuarei usando o conteúdo site em meu proveito aprendendo e dividindo conhecimento com as perguntas e respostas **de qualidade** que aqui se encontram.